# Setting CSS for Launchpage that is different from Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, slim-lang

I have two different sets of CSS files that I want to use for the same website hosted with heroku.

The first set of CSS files are the standard Twitter BootStrap CSS files converted to SASS.
The second set are custom settings for my application.

I have been able to get the look and feel right on my development server but when I upload it to heroku the output is just

```
<body>
<head>
</head>
</body>
```

Please help!

My site is configured as such:

http://imgur.com/S5Aoov1&V3RNQZ3&lSJqpCz&jdSfy82

My controlling layout file is:

```
doctype 5
 html data-uuid=current_user.try(:id)
  = render 'head'
  = render 'third_party_scripts'


 body class=controller_name
  = render 'navbar'
  = render partial: 'account/infobar'
   .container
   = render partial: 'flash', locals: { flash: flash }
   = yield
```

I've duplicated this file and named it "_home.html.slim"
I've changed the contents to:

```
head
 title = t('.title', default: 'My Winning Trade')
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'home', media: 'all'
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'justified-nav', media: 'all'
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shanti|Open+Sans:400,700,800'
  = javascript_include_tag 'jquery'
  = csrf_meta_tags
```

The CSS for my landing pages are called home & justified-nav, based on the jumbotron example provided by twitter bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/

Heroku Error logs after Asset Precompile:

```
2013-10-04T19:48:42.124903+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 384ms
2013-10-04T19:48:42.127966+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:   = stylesheet_link_tag 'home', media: 'all'
2013-10-04T19:48:42.127966+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-04T19:48:42.127966+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: head
2013-10-04T19:48:42.127966+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/sessions.html.slim:3:in `_app_views_layouts_sessions_html_slim__3803347664834042281_69939052542640'
2013-10-04T19:48:42.127966+00:00 app[web.1]:     2:   title = t('.title', default: 'My Winning Trade')
2013-10-04T19:48:42.128146+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-10-04T19:48:42.127966+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (home.css isn't precompiled):
2013-10-04T19:48:42.127966+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   = stylesheet_link_tag 'justified-nav', media: 'all'
2013-10-04T19:48:42.127966+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   = stylesheet_link_tag 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shanti|Open+Sans:400,700,800'
2013-10-04T19:48:42.127966+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   = javascript_include_tag 'jquery'
2013-10-04T19:48:42.127966+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/application/_home.html.slim:3:in `_app_views_application__home_html_slim___3730913017080964654_69939053460220'
2013-10-04T19:48:42.128146+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Comment: Do you just want to add CSS files on specific views or do you want to load both sets of CSS onto the same layout?

Comment: Add the CSS to the specific views. The CSS files clash unfortunately.

Comment: Can you check your heroku logs and the code when you push to the server for any errors or warnings?

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (home.css isn't precompiled):
2013-10-04T19:28:00.568856+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered application/_home.html.slim (129.0ms)
2013-10-04T19:28:00.569276+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 147ms

Comment: If you run `rake assets:precompile` then commited the git code to heroku does the CSS load on heroku?

Comment: The original post has the new heroku error after trying the precompile

Comment: Can you post what your `home.css` file looks like?

Comment: I found the issue, it was related to my production.rb file.

Comment: Glad to see it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're asking.  But it sounds like:

- You have a single layout file.
- You want to load a single set of stylesheets in one set of views
- In another set of views, you want to additionally load a second stylesheet.

Is that correct?  If so, couldn't you just do something like this in your layout:

```
doctype 5
  html data-uuid=current_user.try(:id)
    = render 'head'
    = render 'head_foobar' if controller_name == 'foobar'
```

Comment: That is what I did, but when I pushed that setup to Heroku, it only rendered a blank webpage. The setup you've described works in my Dev environment under POW and Foreman. Its very strange.

Comment: I've done stuff like that on heroku with no problems.  I'm not seeing the code with the conditional statement.  Can you post that?

Comment: doctype 5
    html
      = render 'head' if controller_name == 'application_controller'
      = render 'home' if controller_name == 'sessions_controller'

      body.container class=controller_name
        = yield

Comment: That was in a file called base.html.slim that falls under the views/layouts/ directory.

Comment: I have multiple layout files

Comment: please see the bottom of my original post.

Comment: Hi, sorry, it's a bit confusing how you've laid out your question.  If you could clean things up a bit, we could get to the bottom of this.  For example, you say "My controlling layout file is:" and then you say "I've duplicated this file and named it _home.html.slim" (which is a partial and obviously doesn't/shouldn't look anything like your layout file).  Could you please put all relevant files in your question and make sure to specify the name of the file?

Comment: Also, can you paste your controller code in which you specify what layout to call?  If your controller already contains the logic to decide which layout to call, then you don't need any conditional logic like you pasted for base.html.slim.

Comment: I figured out that it was related to heroku not accepting my precompiled assets, and was not configured properly in my production.rb file. Thank you so much for your help with the conditional statement, I ended up using it in just a single layout file!

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being the home.css file not compiling on the heroku server side.

By changing the production.rb file setting:

from:

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

to:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

The layout configuration that @Manishie suggested worked!

Thank you everyone!